# Application cannot be started virtual desktop error

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, virtual-desktop, winforms

Having a bit of trouble. Recently our company switched to virtual desktops, and I'm currently testing them out.

An application we developed doesn't seem to be installing on these desktops however (see below error, and part of the details). The app was developed in Visual Studio 2019 with VB.NET.

It seems rather generic, and was wondering if anyone has any suggestions.

Note that the application works fine on normal windows 10 desktops/computers.

[image]

[image]

Edit: I should add. I've also created an extremely basic windows form and tested that on the desktop as well, and got the same general error.

Comment: Given that it's a COM exception this sounds like a problem with the software.  This question should include more details and clarify the problem.  For instance we know nothing about the virtual desktop, specifically, the version of Windows it's running.  We need to know a great more like the version of .NET you are targeting.

Comment: Hi. It's Windows 10 version 1909. Regarding .NET, I'm not sure regarding the application we can't get working. However the test app I quickly put together I just left as the default (4.7.2). I don't know much else about the virtual desktop, but the guys who set it up don't know what this error relates to, so I'm just doing a bit of investigating myself as to potential causes.

Comment: [The error message is related to ClickOnce](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/administration/office-365-application-cannot-be-started).  What is the content of `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\`?

Comment: I'll check tomorrow, but I think it's just settings for the app - so that it loads up the same as it was before it was closed. Although I'm not sure this specific error has anything to with ClickOnce. The application won't even install, so it doesn't have a chance to be added to any caches. Plus I created a brand new application and that didn't work either.

Comment: A ClickOnce error would explain the reason you cannot  install the application.

Comment: Okay I'll take a look when I'm next online. Is it just a case of clearing the cache as suggested in that link?

Comment: Before you do anything I want a screenshot of the contents of that folder.

Comment: I had a look but there wasn't really anything in there other than some files like `Appl.0000000` which I think just contain basic settings. I deleted this folder, and tried again but still no luck.